# how to use a javascript module in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file called model-parser.js

it contains:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function getTypes(vitalsModel) {
    var vitals = _.get(vitalsModel, 'vitals');

    var rows = [];
    _.forEach(vitals, function (vital) {
        rows.unshift(Object.keys(vital));
    });

    return rows; 
} 

module.exports.getTypes = getTypes;
```

I want to use the above file in a typescript file.
What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

if you have access to file, just change the extension to .ts and then 
simply write below style import

`import { getTypes , someotherExport } from './yourfile'`
//above statement import individual exports 
or you can import everything in a variable like

```
import * as T from './yourfile'
//use it
T.getTypes()
```

if you don't have access to it, then you can try require

```
declare T:any;
let T = require('yourJS');
T.getTypes()
```

Comment: Note that this is only true in TS 2.1

Comment: thank you it mostly works, except it can not find lodash.

Comment: it still is looking for http://localhost:3000/lodash.js and not finding it. Not clear how to load lodash in a ts file. I have tried npm install --save @types/lodash and import * from "lodash"... still the same error

Comment: lodash has typings so you can do, typings install dt~lodash. and use as import  * as _  from lodash or import { functionName } from lodash